# How to adjust the horizontal width between boxplots inside one facet_wrap() panel and shifting labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to deal separately with those numbers/labels depends on boxplot labels placement for mean and median. They must be place differently in order to provide clarity for the reader. So in case 1 I want mean label value 4.9 place a bit higher above mean line and to the right and median 4.1 value to the right as well, in case 2, I want the same, in case 3 I want median 8.7 value place to the right beside boxplot beside median line respectively, and mean 8.4 value a bit down under red mean line and to the right a bit, in case 4 I want mean 2.5 value move down a bit under a mean line and to the right and median 2.5 value to the right a bit horizontally.
Is it doable ?

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

datas <- structure(list(Pain = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L,
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Female", "Male"
), class = "factor"), `23` = c(3.7, 9.9, 18.1, 12.8, 2.3, 0,
8.7, 3.7, 1.5, 8.6, 5.7, 5.8, 2.1, 1.5, 6.1, 1.6, 0.6, 2.9, 9.1,
7.4, 0, 0, 9.5, 8.7, 4.6, 0, 0, 8.6, 1.6, 7.3, 6.3, 3, 7.8, 2.2,
0.7, 3.9, 2.8, 0.4, 6.2, 1.1, 2.3, 4.9, 4.5, 8, 8.6, 3.9, 1.5,
1.6, 0, 1.4, 3.2, 3.6, 3, 5.1, 4.1, 8.8, 9.6, 0.7)), row.names = c(NA,
-58L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


medians <- ddply(datas, .(Pain, Sex), summarise, m = round(median(`23`), 1))
means <- ddply(datas, .(Pain, Sex), summarise, m = round(mean(`23`), 1))


datas %>%
  dplyr::select(Pain, Sex, `23`) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Pain, Sex) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = `23`, x = Sex, fill = Pain)) +
  geom_boxplot(fatten = 1, outlier.alpha = 0.50, position = position_dodge(width = 1.5), width = 0.8) +
  geom_text(data = medians, aes(x = Sex, y = m, label = m), color = 'blue', vjust = -0.5, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 1.5)) +
  geom_text(data = means, aes(x = Sex, y = m, label = m), color = 'red', vjust = 0.5, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 1.5)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', position = position_dodge(width = 1.5)) +
  stat_summary(aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., color = 'Mean'),
               fun = mean, geom = 'errorbar', width = .75, linetype = 'solid', position = position_dodge(width = 1.5)) +
  stat_summary(aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., color = 'Median'),
               fun = median, geom = 'errorbar', width = .75, linetype = 'solid', position = position_dodge(width = 1.5)) +
  scale_colour_manual('Values', values = c(Median = 'blue', Mean = 'red')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('lightblue', 'lightgreen')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        text = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, vjust = 1),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines")) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Sex), scales = 'free')
```

It gives me this:
[image]

I would like this: [image]

So numbers/labels are not overlapping themselves. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result which first refactors your code to use one data frame of summary stats, gets rid of position_dodge and instead maps `Pain` on `x`, uses a `geom_segment` to draw the lines for the summary stats and finally sets the alignment for the labels:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

box_width <- .6
dat_sum <- datas |>
  summarise(
    median = median(`23`),
    mean = mean(`23`),
    .by = c(Pain, Sex)
  ) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    -c(Pain, Sex),
    names_to = "stat",
    values_to = "m"
  ) |>
  mutate(
    x = as.numeric(factor(Pain)),
    x_label = x + box_width / 2 * if_else(
      Pain == "No", 1, -1
    ),
    hjust = case_when(
      Pain == "Yes" & Sex == "Male" ~ 1,
      Pain == "No" & Sex == "Female" ~ 1,
      .default = 0
    ),
    vjust = case_when(
      stat == "mean" & Sex == "Male" ~ 1,
      .default = 0
    )
  )

datas |>
  select(Pain, Sex, `23`) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = `23`, x = Pain, fill = Pain)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = box_width) +
  geom_boxplot(
    fatten = 1, outlier.alpha = 0.50,
    width = box_width
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = dat_sum,
    aes(
      x = x_label, y = m, label = round(m, 1),
      color = stat, hjust = hjust,
      vjust = vjust
    ),
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    label.padding = unit(2, "pt"),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = dat_sum,
    aes(
      x = x - box_width / 2,
      xend = x + box_width / 2,
      y = m, yend = m,
      color = stat
    )
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Values",
    values = c(mean = "red", median = "blue"),
    labels = c(mean = "Mean", median = "Median")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("lightblue", "lightgreen")
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    text = element_text(size = 12),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, vjust = 1),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Sex), scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed ,absolutely fantastic solution, I will thoroughly analyse your code, as looks very advanced to me, but I will learn a lot. Thanks again.